# How to suppress or set field values to null when duplicated in rows within crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

[I need a formula that will suppress the duplicated details in the set time and op time fields but keep the first entry - if you look at works order 6446:00 in the attached pic the set time and op time entries are repeated and I need to just show these once on the first line they occur - how can i do this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajLfa.png)

Comment: Can you group by work order and suppress details? The last column looks like it might need to be aggregated depending upon your needs.

Comment: Hi CoSpringsGuyI have managed by creating groups on works order and operation to suppress the data in the set and op time fields apart from the 1st entry.  What I cant do is now add up the data (which is in secs) in the group rows as it adds all the data including the suppressed fields.  Any ideas?

Comment: all that should be suppressed is the details section. the rest of the fields just place in the group footer. then create a summary for the op time field

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the Suppression formula.(In the Detail Section (Selection Expert -->Details-->Suppress))

**WorkOrder = Previous(WorkOrder)**

If WorkOrders are same then the Report will suppress Duplicate Records.

I guess this will work for you.